# Long Click event firing on the Button Click in Android

Tags: android, button, click

I have heard that we can create the click event of the Button by holding it for a few moments in Android.

I want to use that functionality in my application.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `View.OnLongClickListener`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
         public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
             return true;
         }
     });
   }
}
```